# Is there any way to let struct type array write to file?

Tags: struct, swift4

I just want to write a struct type array into a file, but after I write it, the file is not created without any error message!!!???

The code :

```
struct temp {
    var a : String = ""
    var b : Date = Date()

    init(
        a : String = "",
        b : Date = Date(),
    ) {
        self.a = ""
        self.b = Date()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var b = [temp]()
    var c = temp()
    c.a = "John"
    c.b = Date()
    b.append(c)
    c.a = "Sally"
    b.append(c)

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent("testFile")

        do{
            (b as NSArray).write(to: fileURL, atomically: true)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

    getTheFile()
}

func getTheFile() {

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent("testFile")
        do {
            print(try String(contentsOf: fileURL))
        }catch{
            print("read error:")
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

It has a error message in getTheFile()

read error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ testFile” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write custom structs to disk. You have to serialize them.

The easist way is the `Codable` protocol and `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder`

```
struct Temp : Codable { // the init method is redundant
    var a = ""
    var b = Date()
}

var documentsDirectory : URL {
    return  try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var b = [Temp]()
    var c = Temp()
    c.a = "John"
    c.b = Date()
    b.append(c)
    c.a = "Sally"
    b.append(c)

    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("testFile.plist")
    do {
        let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(b)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        getTheFile()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getTheFile() {
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("testFile.plist")
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let temp = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Temp].self, from: data)
        print(temp)
    } catch {
        print("read error:", error)
    }
}
```

Note:

In Swift **never** use the `NSArray/NSDictionary` APIs to read and write property lists. Use either `Codable` or `PropertyListSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

If the array's contents are all property list objects (like: NSString, NSData, NSArray, NSDictionary) then only you can use writeToFile method to write the array in a file.
Here in your implementation, the array contains structure which is a value type, not an object. This is why you are getting an error.